# How to create custom keyboard app in react native with your own fonts?

Tags: react-native

I want to build a keyboard app in react native that will have custom fonts and work with every other app in my mobile.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3nTfZ7SUJw
<- example. i want to build similar app in react native. is it possible to build in react native?

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for the same thing but so far I have realized it is not possible with react native and with hybrid development. Native development will be required for example in android we can use Kotlin or Java